# How to get JDK 8 default XML transformer to emit "&apos;" for apostrophes

Tags: java, xml, entity

I have a third-party webservice that can only parse XML requests where apostrophes in attributes are encoded as `&apos;`. It rejects raw apostrophes like `'`. This webservice **does not care** for your argument that the XML standards allow apostophes in attribute values that are delimited by double-quotes. It wants `&apos;`.

I want to use the standard Java XML transformer to generate the XML for these requests. It does not encode `'` as `&apos;`. How can I make it do that?

Sample program:

```
class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        final org.w3c.dom.Document doc = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        final org.w3c.dom.Element tag = doc.createElement("fedora");
        tag.setAttribute("tip", "m'lady");
        doc.appendChild(tag);
        doc.setXmlStandalone(true);
        final javax.xml.transform.Transformer t = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        t.setOutputProperty(javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");
        t.setOutputProperty(javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        t.setOutputProperty(javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
        t.transform(new javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource(doc),
                    new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(new java.io.PrintWriter(System.out)));
    }
}
```

What it emits: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><fedora tip="m'lady"/>`

What I want it to emit: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><fedora tip="m&apos;lady"/>`

Comment: Generally, the serialization facilities in XSLT and JAXP are designed on the assumption that the output will be consumed by a conformant XML parser. As soon as you have components in your system that don't conform to standards, your costs are vastly increased because other off-the shelf components become unusable.

Answer (score 0):

### XSLT 2.0 Solution

In XSLT 2.0+, you can use [**character maps**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps):

```
<xsl:character-map name="aposCharMap">
  <xsl:output-character character="'" string="&amp;apos;"/>
</xsl:character-map>
```

This will substitute `&apos;` for `'` during serialization.